# How to monitor variables in GDB and log it if it meets certain conditions?

Tags: c, gdb

I would like to know if there is any way in which I can monitor a value of a variable until for example a counter reaches a value and then log the output of variable value during each counter value?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Set a watch point on the counter:

```
(gdb) watch var
```

And make that watchpoint conditional:

```
(gdb) cond <watchpoint_number> var>=value
```

If you want to log to a file:

```
(gdb) set logging file <filename>
(gdb) set logging on
```

By default gdb logs to gdb.txt

Comment: How do I log it to an output file? what is th epath of default log file if I say "set logging on"

Answer (score 4):

You can use [watchpoints](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbwatch.html) to make gdb monitor the value of a variable, and break execution of the program when the value changes. Once execution is stopped, you can use gdb's command set to inspect and print the value. I'm not sure if you can script gdb to do this automatically each time it breaks.

Comment: This might help https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html

Comment: @Jerinaw What answer are you talking about?

Comment: You wrote "Yes, you can do that too - check out the "commands" command..." it would have been more helpful to provide a link to the command that answers the question.

Comment: Here is a link to the commands command

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands