# How to automatically analyse when a C pointer variable is assigned to NULL

Tags: c, gdb

I have a long C code which gets segmentation fault because a pointer variable `x` is pointed to `NULL` somewhere in the code (there are many writes to this variable and I did not write the code myself), and later an attempt has been made to read it's value resulting in a segmentation fault.

Now I can get the line where the variable `x` was accessed which resulted the `segfault` using `gdb`, but I'm interested to know when it (`x`) was assigned to the value `NULL`. There are many writes to this variable in the code and checking this manually soon becomes tedious. Is there an automated way to find *when some variable `x` is assigned to a specific value?* Maybe using `gdb` or some value analysis tool?

Comment: Set a watchpoint? Something like `watch x`?

Comment: Building off of @EOF's comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099537/how-to-monitor-variables-in-gdb-and-log-it-if-it-meets-certain-conditions?rq=1

Comment: It might not be assigned a specific value of `NULL` by a code statement. It could be because that's the default initialisation of a global variable, or in a block of memory obtained by `calloc()`, or the *partial* explicit initialisation of a `struct` or `array` which would fill the rest with `0` .

Comment: ..or a buffer index overrun, or an overwrite via some other pointer, maybe in another thread in another module in an unrelated subsystem.  Not trying to be depressing, or anything..

Comment: Thanks everyone for the informative comments. If I understand the comments correctly, value of a pointer variable `x` may become `null` in any of the ways mentioned above. Or, it might get corrupted in many ways and may later point to an illegal memory address, accessing which may cause `segfault`. Is there a way to check all of these possibilities with `gdb`?